# Host (baseband) controller in mobile phone

Tags: microcontroller, controller, gsm, mobile

Hi mobile world I met many times the term "host controller" or "baseband controller" used interchangeably in the context of being the heart of the mobile. What exaclty is that, som SoC with CPU, GPU, GSM modem???

Answer (score 1):

Typically the 'host' refers to the master device/entity that belongs to the 
side of the computer. It could be inside computer or external to a computer.
[it could be a microcontroller , but the point is host is more closer to you
when you writing software to work with].

The main idea is before you communicate with the other device, you communicate 
with the host, for a example hard disk controller is a host, USB controller chip
is a host.

So according to your GSM module thing, The chip hardware/software that parsing the
AT command set and act as a front end is refereed as a host.

Your Manual/Specification probably should have a chapter called terms and Abbreviations.
Turn out for that page and you'll find the specific abbreviation which is specific to
your module.